# Giving the distribution law of the number of experience

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

the probability that  a certain event occurs is 0,6. The experience is conducted until the event occurs but no more than 4 times. I should give the distribution of the number of experience

It is

1-0,6  the probability that the event occurs on the 1st experience is 0,6

2-0,24 the probability that the event occurs on the 2nd experience is 0,4*0,6

3-0,096 the probability that the event occurs on the 3rd experience is 0,4*0,4*0,6

4- 0,064 I think the probability should be 0,4*0,4*0,4*0,6 which is 0,0384, but this is the wrong number. The answer is 0,064

Anyone can help understand why the probability that the event occurs on 4th experience is 0,064?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ be the number of experiments.

The event $X=4$ can happen in two ways: (i) we get $3$ failures in a row and then a success or (ii) we get $3$ failures in a row and then failure.

Thus $X=4$ happens precisely if there are $3$ failures in a row. This is $(0.4)^3$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in the wording of the problem. The probability that the event occurs at the 4th trial/experience is exactly what you have calculated but in order for the number of experience to be $4$, you also have to take into account the probability that the event does not happen even in the 4th experience. So, simply subtract from $1$, the previous three probabilities that you obtain :-)